# traceback = Can't convert 'type' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

**Problem**:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Python34/my code/types.py", line 2, in      print(
>   race , 'is' + type( race )) TypeError: Can't convert 'type' object to
>   str implicitly

Open an IDLE Edit Window and initialize a variable by assigning it a string, then display its value and data type

```
race = ‘Daytona 500’
print( race , ‘is‘ + type( race ) )
```

Next, initialize a variable by assigning it a whole number then display its value and data type

```
kilo = 1000
print( kilo , ‘is‘ + type( kilo ) )
```

Now, initialize a variable by assigning it a decimal number, then display its value and data type

```
temp = 98.6
print( temp , ‘is‘ + type( temp ) )
```

Initialize a variable by assigning it a truth keyword then display its value and data type

```
flag = True
print( flag , ‘is‘ + type( flag ) )
```

Finally, replace the last variable value with a truth result of a comparison, then again display its value and data type

```
flag = 4 > 8
print( flag , ‘is‘ + type( flag ) )
```

Save then run the program to discover the types of data stored within the variables you have created

**OK,so this is what I coded what is wrong?:**

```
race = 'Daytona 500'
print( race , 'is' + type( race ))

kilo = 1000
print( kilo , 'is' + type( kilo))

temp = 98.6
print( temp , 'is' + type( temp))

flag = True
print( flag , 'is' + type( flag))

flag = 4>8
print( flag , 'is' + type( flag))
```

Comment: please properly format your code using the `{}` button in the editing window

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a + symbol instead replace with commas. So the code would then be:

```
race = 'Daytona 500'

print( race , 'is' , type( race ))

kilo = 1000

print( kilo , 'is' , type( kilo))

temp = 98.6

print( temp , 'is' , type( temp))

flag = True

print( flag , 'is' , type( flag))

flag = 4>8

print( flag , 'is' , type( flag))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   race = 'Daytona 500'

   print( race , 'is' + str(type( race )))

   kilo = 1000

   print( kilo , 'is' + str(type( kilo)))

   temp = 98.6

   print( temp , 'is' + str(type( temp)))

   flag = True

   print( flag , 'is' + str(type( flag)))

   flag = 4>8

   print( flag , 'is' + str(type( flag)))
```

Python expects an explicit typecast to `str` for non-string types if trying to concatenate it to a string.

Comment: why isn't str(race) needed?

Comment: `race` is already a of type `str` (you defined it as a string), versus the others are either of type `type`, `int`, `double` or `bool`

Comment: You don't need to "str-ize" `kilo` in `print( str(kilo) , 'is' + str(type( kilo)))`, `print` will do that for you. Its the attempted string concatenation in `'is' + type(kilo)` that's the problem. When you do `'is' + str(type(kilo))` you get `"isint"` (note the lack of a space).